# Footer space from page bottom change suddenly after page no. 4

Tags: footer

I wrote a tex file using texstudio (miktex) and when I compile it footer space from bottom of the page changes after a specific page (for me page no. 4). I have used \fancyheader but the problem doesn't seem to be related to this package. I removed and commented everything I thought it might help but still no luck.

````
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=magenta]{hyperref}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{fourier-orns}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[all]{nowidow}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage[computeautoilg=on]{xepersian}
\settextfont[Scale=1.32]{HM FElmi}
\setlatintextfont[Scale=1.2]{Latin Modern Roman}

\ExplSyntaxOn \cs_set_eq:NN \etex_iffontchar:D \tex_iffontchar:D \ExplSyntaxOff

%\setdigitfont[Scale=1.32]{HM XKayhan}
\setmathdigitfont{HM FElmi}
\DeclareMathSizes{10.95}{14.4}{8.4}{6}

\author{}

\title{
    \begin{figure}[t]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{besm.eps}
    \end{figure}
    
    \begin{center}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{logo.eps}
    \end{center}}

\SepMark{-}

\begin{document}
    
    \titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{6pt}{12pt}
    \titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{6pt}{12pt}
    %\pagenumbering{harfi}

    \addtolength{\footnotesep}{6pt}
    \setlength{\skip\footins}{12pt}
    
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \maketitle
        
    {\small \tableofcontents}
        
    {\small \listoffigures}
        
    {\small \listoftables}
    
    \newpage
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    
    \renewcommand\headrule{%
        \vspace{-6pt}
        \hrulefill}
    
    \renewcommand\footrule{%
        \hrulefill\raisebox{-2.1pt}
        {\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad}
        \hrulefill\hrulefill}
    
    \renewcommand{\labelitemi}{--}
    
    \fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
    \fancyhead[R]{{\small \leftmark}}
    %\fancyhead[L]{{\small \rightmark}}
    \fancyfoot{} % clear all footer fields
    \fancyfoot[L]{{\small شرکت سرمایه‌گذار:}}
    \fancyfoot[R]{{\small تاریخ: \today}}
    \fancyfoot[C]{{\small{\decofourleft\enspace\thepage\enspace\decofourright}}}
    %\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
    %\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
    
    
    \chapter{معرفی طرح}
    \section{مقدمه} 

نیروگاه‌های خورشیدی فتوولتائیک مجموعه تجهیزات و دستگاههایی هستند که نور خورشید را به انرژی الکتریکی تبدیل می‌کنند و برای منازل مسکونی، مکان‌های اداری، ساختمان‌ها، خیابان‌ها و غیره قابل پیاده‌سازی و استفاده هستند. اصولاً نیروگاه‌های خورشیدی متصل به شبکه مرکب از سه قسمت زیر هستند:
    
    \begin{itemize}[noitemsep]
        \item
    پنل‌های خورشیدی یا ماژولهای فتوولتائیک که وظیفه تولید انرژی برق را بر عهده دارند.
        \item
    اینورترها که جریان مستقیم را به جریان متناوب تبدیل می‌کنند.
        \item
    اجزای جانبی سیستم شامل سیم‌کشی‌ها، کلیدها و سوئیچ‌ها، سازه‌های پشتیبانی و ...
    \end{itemize}

    اساس کار نیروگاه‌های خورشیدی به این صورت است که نور به پنل‌های خورشیدی می‌تابد و در اثر آن انرژی فوتون مستقیماً به انرژی الکتریکی تبدیل می‌شود. جریان برق تولیدشده توسط پنل‌های خورشیدی جریان مستقیم (\lr{DC}) است که برای استفاده در وسایل برقی معمول در منازل و نیاز روزمره بایستی مشابه برق شهر به جریان متناوب (\lr{AC}) تبدیل شود که این کار توسط دستگاهی به نام اینورتر انجام می‌گیرد. نظر به اینکه میزان تابش خورشید در ایران بین 1800 الی 2200 کیلووات ساعت بر مترمربع در سال تخمین زده می‌شود و بعلاوه ایران به‌طور متوسط 280 روز آفتابی دارد، کشورمان به لحاظ دریافت انرژی خورشید در بالاترین رده‌های جهانی قرار دارد. بنابراین استفاده از انرژی رایگان خورشید و به‌کارگیری آن در نیروگاه‌های خورشیدی برای تأمین برق نویدبخش آینده‌ای پایدار و پاک برای کشورمان خواهد بود.
    \section{هدف پروژه} 
    با توجه به ضرورت تأمین رشد حدوداً 10 درصدی تقاضای برق در هر سال و وجود پتانسیل خورشیدی فراوان در ایران، استفاده از نیروگاه‌های خورشیدی می‌تواند راه‌حلی مطلوب برای تأمین انرژی پاک و پایدار باشد. این گزارش به بررسی فنی طرح اتصال یک واحد نیروگاه خورشیدی به ظرفیت \textbf{2 مگاوات} می‌پردازد که به فیدر متصل می‌گردد. در ‏شکل \ref{fig:11} پیکربندی مدل تولیدی به کار رفته در این پروژه نشان داده شده است. این ساختار متشکل از پنل‌های خورشیدی و تجهیزات وابستۀ آن همچون سیم و کابل، کابینت تجمیع سلول‌های خورشیدی و پُست تجمیع اینورتر و ترانس افزاینده و یک مجموعه کلیدابزار ولتاژ متوسط می‌باشد.
    
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}{0.25\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[height=0.1\textheight]{1.jpg}
            \caption{پنل خورشیدی}
        \end{subfigure}%
        \begin{subfigure}{0.25\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[height=0.1\textheight]{2.jpg}
            \caption{اینورتر}
        \end{subfigure}%
        \begin{subfigure}{0.25\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[height=0.1\textheight]{3.jpg}
            \caption{کلید ابزار}
        \end{subfigure}%
        \begin{subfigure}{0.25\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[height=0.1\textheight]{4.jpg}
            \caption{شبکه برق}
        \end{subfigure}%
        \caption{طرح پیکربندی نیروگاه خورشیدی}\label{fig:11}
    \end{figure}

    \section{محل پست بالادست و فاصله تقریبی تا ساختگاه} 
    این بخش شامل مشخصات مکان نصب نیروگاه مطابق جدول \ref{tab:11} و پُست بالادست و فاصله تقریبی تا محل احداث نیروگاه مطابق شکل \ref{fig:12} می‌باشد. اطلاعات لازم برای محاسبات انرژی خورشیدی از مراجع موجود استخراج شده است. اطلاعات جغرافیایی از طریق سیستم \lr{GIS} به دست آمده و اطلاعات هواشناسی و محاسبات خورشیدی با استفاده از نرم‌افزارهای \lr{Meteonorm} و \lr{PVSyst} انجام شده است. اطلاعات نرم‌افزار هواشناسی و داده‌های خورشیدی و شبیه‌سازی نرم‌افزاری به ترتیب در پیوست «الف» و «ب» آورده شده است.
    
    \begin{table}[H]
        \centering
        %\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
        \caption{مختصات محل احداث نیروگاه در دستگاه \lr{UTM}}
        \label{tab:11}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            \lr{Zone: 39R} & \lr{Hemisphere: N} & \lr{Y=1} & \lr{X=2}\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{plant_loc}
        \caption{موقعیت نیروگاه مزرعه خورشیدی  روی فیدر }
        \label{fig:12}
    \end{figure}
    
    \section{ویژگی‌ها و مزایای سیستم معرفی‌شده} 
    از بارزترین ویژگی‌های طرح پیشنهادی می‌توان به موارد زیر اشاره نمود:
    
    \begin{itemize}[noitemsep]
        \item
    صرفه‌جویی در انرژی حاصل از سوخت‌های فسیلی و کاهش آلودگی هوا و حفاظت محیط زیست که به‌واسطه استفاده از انرژی فتوولتائیک بدون ایجاد هرگونه آلودگی (بر خلاف سایر نیروگاه‌های سوختی که هم خودشان مصرف انرژی بیشتری دارند، هم محیط‌زیست را آلوده می‌کنند و هم ذخایر انرژی تجدیدناپذیر را با بازده پایین از بین می‌برند) حاصل می‌شود.
        \item
    افزایش بهره‌وری زمین‌های بدون کاربرد و بایر.
        \item
    ساختار مطمئن و قابل اطمینان با بازده بالای فنی و اقتصادی به واسطه استفاده از تجهیزات باکیفیت و مطالعات دقیق.
        \item
    انعطاف‌پذیری در سایز و پیکربندی سیستم به دلیل ماژولار بودن واحدها به هنگام نصب.
        \item
    استفاده از استانداردها از مرحله طراحی تا پیاده‌سازی برای ایمنی و کارایی بالا.
    \end{itemize}

    \chapter{اجزای نیروگاه و اصول طراحی}
    \section{آرایۀ فتوولتائیک}
    آرایه فتوولتائیک با اجتماع پنلهای فتوولتائیک تشکیل می‌شود. پنل‌ها خود از ماژول‌های فتوولتائیک ساخته می‌شوند؛ ماژول‌های فتوولتائیک نیز متشکل از سلول‌های فتوولتائیک هستند. ‏شکل \ref{fig:21} سلول، ماژول، پنل و آرایه فتوولتائیک را نشان می‌دهد. چهار نوع اصلی سلول‌های فتوولتائیک عبارت‌اند از: مونوکریستال، پلی‌کریستال، سلول‌های آمورف و سلول‌های نانو فتوولتائیک که جدیدترین سلول خورشیدی معرفی‌شده می‌باشند. برای تولید توان مناسب، آرایه‌های فتوولتائیک را در حالت‌های مختلف می‌توان به هم وصل نمود. برای رسیدن به ولتاژ بالاتر، آرایه‌ها با یکدیگر سری و برای رسیدن به جریان بیشتر با یکدیگر موازی می‌شوند و یا حتی می‌توان به‌صورت سری–موازی آن‌ها را به یکدیگر متصل نمود. مشخصات ماژول‌های فتوولتائیک به کار رفته در این پروژه به شرح پیوست «پ» می‌باشد.
\end{document}```
````

Comment: please provide an example that shows the problem, you have posted a lot of code but we can not test it as no `\documentclass`  but `\title{    \begin{figure}[t]` is completely wrong you should never have a float in a title, preferably you should have no markup at all, just text.

Comment: fancyhdr is known to change page geometries on the fly.  It should send you a warning message to that effect.  You probably will need to increase \footskip,, or \smash something.